# Node.js, Express, and GM (GraphicsMagick) - Adding watermarks and general image processing efficiency

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I need to create 4 image sizes from an uploaded photo: large, medium, small, and extra small. It's working for the most part with the code below, but also the large and medium sizes need to have a watermark put in the bottom left, but not the smaller two sizes.

It seems like for the watermarked images, I'll need to duplicate the file stream and save out a separate instance for each one. Speed and efficiency are important here, so I want to make sure I'm doing this the best way.

The GM node module is really lacking in documentation. For more information they link to the GraphicsMagick site, which doesn't help if you're trying to do this with the GM module. It's really frustrating.

So basically, I could use help figuring out how to do the watermarks on the two larger sizes, and then also I just want to know if the code below is as efficient as it could be. It seems a bit slow when creating the 4 sizes on my local machine.

```
var fileName = req.files.photo.name,
    fileBaseName = fileName.substr(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')),
    uploadRoot = SiteConfig.root + '/upload/',
    photosRoot = SiteConfig.root + '/photos/',
    publicRoot = SiteConfig.root + '/public/';

require('fs').rename(
    req.files.photo.path,
    uploadRoot + fileName,
    function(error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            res.send({ error: 'upload error' });
            return;
        }

        var ImageSizes = {
            large: {
                width: 990,
                height: 990
            },
            medium: {
                width: 550,
                height: 550
            },
            small: {
                width: 145,
                height: 145
            },
            xsmall: {
                width: 55,
                height: 55
            }
        };

        var GM = require('gm'),
            fileStream = require('fs').createReadStream(photosRoot + fileName);

        var lgPath = photosRoot + fileBaseName + '_lg.jpg',
            mdPath = photosRoot + fileBaseName + '_md.jpg',
            smPath = photosRoot + fileBaseName + '_sm.jpg',
            xsPath = photosRoot + fileBaseName + '_xs.jpg';

        // I'm guessing the second parameter is to set the format
        GM(fileStream, 'img.jpg')
            .size(
                {
                    bufferStream: true
                },
                function(err, size)
                {
                    console.log(size.width);
                    console.log(size.height);

                    if (size.width > ImageSizes.large.width || size.height > ImageSizes.large.height)
                        this.resize(ImageSizes.large.width, ImageSizes.large.height);

                    // Auto-orient based on EXIF data then remove EXIF data
                    this
                        .autoOrient()
                        .noProfile()
                        .quality(70)
                        .write(
                            lgPath,
                            function (err)
                            {
                                if (!err)
                                {
                                    console.log('write large done');

                                    this
                                        .resize(ImageSizes.medium.width, ImageSizes.medium.height)
                                        // watermark code - i want to continue using the file stream instead of a file path
                                        //.subCommand('composite')
                                        //.gravity('Center')
                                        //.in('-compose', 'Over', watermarkFilePath, baseFilePath)
                                        .quality(70)
                                        .write(
                                            mdPath,
                                            function (err)
                                            {
                                                if (!err)
                                                {
                                                    console.log('write medium done');

                                                    this
                                                        .resize(ImageSizes.small.width, ImageSizes.small.height)
                                                        .crop(ImageSizes.small.width, ImageSizes.small.height)
                                                        .quality(70)
                                                        .write(
                                                            smPath,
                                                            function (err)
                                                            {
                                                                if (!err)
                                                                {
                                                                    console.log('write small done');

                                                                    this
                                                                        .resize(ImageSizes.xsmall.width, ImageSizes.xsmall.height)
                                                                        .quality(70)
                                                                        .write(
                                                                            xsPath,
                                                                            function (err)
                                                                            {
                                                                                if (!err)
                                                                                    console.log('write xsmall done');
                                                                                else
                                                                                    console.log('write xsmall error');
                                                                            }
                                                                        );

                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                    console.log('write small error');
                                                            }
                                                        );
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    console.log('write medium error');
                                            }
                                        );
                                }
                                else
                                    console.log('write large error');
                            }
                        );


                }
            );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

(note this is not real code, just an idea about what the real code might want to look like)

It strikes me that you want to do something like this:

```
server.on('incomingImage', function (image, res) {
  async.each(imageOptions, function (imageOptions, done) {
     image
       .pipe(resize(imageOptions))
       .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(baseDir + image.path + imageOptions.path))
       .on('end', done);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
       res.send(500);
    } else {
       res.send(204);
    }
  });
});
```

Which is to say, when an image comes in, create a resizing through stream and a file writing stream for each image option, then pipe the image through all the resizing streams on to the file writting streams, once all the files have been written, respond.

By doing the processing in parallel, with streams, you minimize any wait time the server would have to do due to IO (which is the basic idea behind node.js in the first place).

As is you are writing the file to disk, then processing each image option in turn and writing them to disk before starting in on reading the file from disk yet again.

So that's write time x 1 + read time x 5 + process time x 5 + write time x 5

Instead it should be max process time + max write time which is much shorter.

There are some complications since the `gm` module doesn't provide a nice stream interface.  You might want to see if there's a better module.

Also on the topic of streams:

https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook
http://nodeschool.io/#stream-adventure

and on async

http://nodeschool.io/#asyncyou